# Can i use native javascript for loop within jquery code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Can i use native javascript for loop within jquery code? I have a construct in which `$.each` does not seem feasible. How can I loop in this situation?

the code inside the for loop is not working. any advice would be appreciated.

```
if (item.relate){
    $(prodHeading).append(item.name);
    if (item.image) {$(prodContent).append(item.image);}
    if (item.description) {
        $(prodContentText).append(item.description); 
        $(prodContent).append(prodContentText);
    }
    $(prodBox).append(prodHeading);
    $(prodBox).append(prodContent);

    //going to look for other attached items

    for (j=0; j<10; j++){
        var prodBox = $(document.createElement('div')).attr('class','productBox');
        var prodHeading = $(document.createElement('div')).attr('class','productBoxHeading');
        var prodContent = $(document.createElement('div')).attr('class','productBoxContent');
        var prodContentText = $(document.createElement('div')).attr('class','text');

        if ('item.image'+j) {$(prodContent).append(item.image);}
        if ('item.description'+j) {
            $(prodContentText).append(item.description); 
            $(prodContent).append(prodContentText);
        }
        $(prodBox).append(prodHeading); 
        $(prodBox).append(prodContent);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you want to loop through?

Comment: Don't you think your a missing a var in j=0? like for(var j = 0; j<10; j++=

Comment: Are you getting any errors? The loop itself is standard...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First,

```
for (j=0; j<10; j++){
```

should be using a declared variable:

```
for (var j=0; j<10; j++){
```

Second,

```
if ('item.image'+j) {
```

does not make much sense. Every such string will pass an `if` condition. If you are looking whether an element exists, use:

```
if ($('item.image'+j).length) {
```

Comment: the ('item.image'+j) is actually calling a json element. and it is not working like that. this code is inside a $.each loop. can you suggest what to do if i want to toggle through all the item.image(0-9)??

Comment: @amit: You're currently combining strings, nothing more. If you want accessing a dynamic property of an object, you can use `item['image' + j]`, which equals to `item.image0` if `j` is equal to `0`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use regular javascript with JQuery.

What is this if statement meant to do?

```
if ('item.description'+j)
```

There is no comparison happening, so it will always be true.

Answer (score 0):

```
  for (var j=0; j<10; j++){
                    var prodBox = $(document.createElement('div')).attr('class','productBox');
                    var prodHeading = $("<div/>",{class:'productBoxHeading'});    
                    var prodContent = $("<div/>",{class:'productBoxContent'}); 
                    var prodContentText = $("<div/>",{class:'text'}); 


                    if (item.image+j) {prodContent.append(item.image);}
                    if (item.description+j) {
                        prodContentText.append(item.description); 
                        prodContent.append(prodContentText);
                        }
                    prodBox.append(prodHeading); 
                    prodBox.append(prodContent);
                    }
```